# How to create a list based on a max value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a list

`@list = [1], [2], ... ,[8]`

based on a variable which contains a numerical value `MAX = 8` in sql server.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do that

```
DECLARE @var INT = 8

DECLARE @list VARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH C AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) AS n
  FROM sys.all_objects 
)
SELECT @list =
STUFF((SELECT ', [' + CAST(n AS VARCHAR(5)) + ']' AS [text()]
        FROM  
        (SELECT n FROM C WHERE n <= @var
         ) x
        For XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @list
```